# QByteArray filled with \x....\x.... to QString

Tags: c++, qt, escaping, qstring, qbytearray

I'm receiving serial data trough a QByteArray in the following way

```
QByteArray serialdata = testport->readAll();
qDebug() << serialdata;
```

qDebug spills out things like

> ...\x00T\xAAN\x82v\xA9k\x7F\xEE\xCEMf\x1C\xAA...

I know there are Strings/Chars behind this, but have absolute no clue what format is used. I've searched Bing and this board but found no clue. What confuses my even more is, that those pieces have a different length. Some are \x12, some are \x123 or even \x1234.

Can anyone tell me what Codec or format that is and how I transform that into a QString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qDebug` formats the array so that it can be safely displayed, i.e. turns the display format into the format of a C string literal, where non-ASCII-printable characters are escaped and represented as hex octets.

Namely, `\xab` means a byte with a value of `a*16+b`, where `a` and `b` are hexadecimal digits.

`\x1234` means `{0x12, '3', '4'}`.

`\x00T\xAAN\x82v\xA9k\x7F\xEE\xCEMf\x1C\xAA` means
`{0x00, 'T', 0xAA, 'N', 0x82, 'v', 0xA9, 'k', 0x7F, 0xEE, 0xCE, 'M', 'f', 0x1C, 0xAA}`. This is a "string" but definitely not a string in any natural human language, or at least not in any of the common encodings.

It's most definitely **not** an ASCII string. Looks more like line noise. Most likely you have not set the communication settings on the port to match those of the device you communicate with.

Comment: thx. Is there any function to transform a QByteArray like `\x00T\xAAN\x82v\xA9k\x7F\xEE\xCEMf\x1C\xAA` into a Unicode QString?

Comment: Yes. But it depends on the encoding, and what you show here looks like no Unicode encoding I know of, unless the data is in a language that uses no Latin alphabet.

Comment: Those strings hiding in the QByteArray aren't natural human language but so calles NMEA0183 sentences like **!AIVDM,1,1,,B,13aDrb5P1gPOO<@M>ADs8gw:25kD,0*32** by the way.

Comment: The NMEA sentences are all in Latin alphabet with Roman numerals. I.e. they are ASCII. The array you show is **not**, and doesn't look like NMEA0183. `qDebug()` will dump NMEA sentences without resorting to any escapes. Have you set the correct baudrate and other low-level protocol settings on the `QSerialPort`? Recall that NMEA0183 is either 4800bps or 38400bps, not e.g. 9600 (the default for most serial I/O implementations, including `QSerialPort`).

Comment: damn. tried to make this as low level as possible and forgot to set the baudrate. now i get clear messages with qDebug. thx dude. you saved my day!